# "File not open for reading" Flask after PDF splitting

Tags: python, api, flask, python-requests

I'm trying to split a PDF file that gets as a post request to this Flask API. I am using PyPDF2 to work with the pdf files and I'm getting this error when trying to post the freshly split pdf: "IOError: File not open for reading". I tried opening it again before the post but that causes another type of error.

```
from flask import render_template, request
from app import app
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import requests


@app.route('/')
def start():
    return render_template('home.html')


#upload-route
@app.route('/upload', methods = ['POST'])
def upload():
    pdf_data = None 
    split_pages = []
    if 'pdf' in request.files:
        incoming_pdf = request.files['pdf']
        pdf_data = PdfFileReader(incoming_pdf, 'rb') 
        for i in range(pdf_data.numPages):
            output = PdfFileWriter()
            output.addPage(pdf_data.getPage(i))
            with open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb").read() as outputStream:
            ##new_page = output.write(outputStream)
                try:
                    split_pages.append(output)
                    print('Created: {}'.format("document-page%s.pdf" % i))
                    files  = {'userfile': outputStream }
                    upload_url ='*URL IM POSTING TO*'
                    auth_upload={
                        *AUTH KEYS*
                    }
                    r=requests.post(url=upload_url, files=files,data=auth_upload)
                finally:
                    outputStream.close()

    else:
        return "please upload a file to process"
```

I know this may be a super basic question but I have spent an outrageous amount of time with this and I no longer think straight.

Comment: `"document-page%s.pdf" % i` is the old way of inserting values inside strings. Does your version of Python even support that now? We would expect to see something like `"document-page{}.pdf".format(i)` nowadays. Admittedly we would also expect to see something other than  `IOError: File not open for reading` in the way of an error but perhaps the `%i` is confusing the error trapping.

Comment: Are you not opening this file as Write / Binary then calling the read function of it ? ```open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb").read()``` . That seems incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had look at your code, and what about that?

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

with open('./reklamacja.pdf', 'rb') as my_pdf:
    pdf_data = PdfFileReader(my_pdf) 
    for i in range(pdf_data.numPages):
        output = PdfFileWriter()
        # output.addPage(pdf_data.getPage(i))
        output.insertPage(pdf_data.getPage(i))
        filename = "document-page%s.pdf" % i
        with open(filename, "wb") as outputStream:
            output.write(outputStream)

        with open(filename, 'rb') as file_to_send:
            r = requests.post('http://someurl.bin', files={'myname': file_to_send})


        { Some other code...}
```

Build that into your flask code, it should work.
For me you just overcomplicated a little it in 'try' block :)
Hope this solves you problem.

Comment: Thank you! this ended up working for me. I finally understood that I had to handle it differently when writting vs reading, thanks again!